# SQL Server Management Studio 18.0 missing Tasks option on right click

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I installed SQL Server Management Studio 18.0... But missing Tasks option on right click... Need to Import Data from excel to Table

I have installed following:

SQL Server 2017

Sql Server Management Studio 18

SQL Server Data Tools - I don't know I need it or not but just installed it..

[SQL Server Management Studi Right Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZPoc.jpg)

Not sure what did I do wrong.

Another Image... Import Data Grayed out...
[Import Data Grayed Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C6eh.jpg)

SSMS Version 15.0
[SSMS Version 15.0 Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oboav.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expand ( click the plus sign ) on databases and then right click on a particular database then to see tasks option.

Comment: @Vip - It could be because of installation. You can still import data from csv using the flat file option.  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34525990-include-64-bit-import-and-export-wizard-in-ssms-re

Comment: @Vip - Glad that the answer has helped you. Please consider voting up it as it matters in Stack overflow.

Comment: Well, I may have just aced the 'Mistake of the Day' award!